# How to figure out which files, libraries a program needs in windows?

Tags: windows

I have a Windows program X.

How can figure out which libraries, files ...etc are used by X?

So if any of these files are deleted from my Windows then X will not run without errors.

Comment: What kind of “libraries, files, etc.” are you thinking of? Is there a specific program that you are having trouble running?

Comment: I have a program and want to list all libraries, files that it depends on. I am trying to run a program in Linux using WINE. I thought this will help me do it.

Comment: Is it not working in WINE? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: I did not try that yet, but I read that it is not running using WINE and I thought I should start by this question. :)

Comment: Where did you read it? Did they give more details about *why* it won’t run? If someone said it won’t run, then presumably they already tried to get it to work. Perhaps it uses a Windows API function that WINE doesn’t support yet. Either way, you can try the two suggestions below to get a head start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program’s prerequisites will depend on that specific program. There is no universal set of prerequisites or even universal *type* of prerequisite.

The closest thing (in Windows) would be DLLs and .NET frameworks.

- You can find out what DLLs it uses with the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
- You can sort of find out what .NET framework it uses (if any) [with some effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run). Other than that, you should just check the program’s documentation (specifically `readme.txt`).

Comment: (Let me know how it goes. If it doesn’t work out, we can try to figure out something else.)

Comment: I got this: "Error: At least one file was not a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module." but the program runs smoothly in Windows 7

Comment: Is it a Windows Vista/7/8 program? I can’t determine if WINE supports Vista+ applications yet, but if not, then it won’t run programs that were compiled specifically for Vista and up (in fact, you cannot even run the Windows calculator or notepad from Vista or up on Windows XP).